# Stretching out JScrollPane - Java

Tags: java, jtable, jscrollpane

I have this structure:

```
<JFrame>
         <JPanel backgroundcolor = "pink">
            <JScrollPane>
                <JTable>!!!Data here !!!</JTable>
            </JScrollPane>
         </JPanel>
</JFrame>
```

How do i stretch the ScrollPane it to cover the full window without using setSize?
This is how it looks like now:
[alt text http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/8491/17747996.png](http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/8491/17747996.png)

Thanks!

Comment: How are you adding your `JTable` to your `JScrollPane` and your `JScrollPane` to your `JPanel`?

Comment: JTable table = new JTable(data, columnHeaders);
table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
add(scrollPane); (coz the parent JPanel component is extended in the class).

Comment: Correct etiquette here is to answer your own question using the answer box below, rather than commenting/editing your question.  Please roll back your changes, post your own answer, and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mmmph! Nobody offered a simple solution such as using BorderLayout as layout manager for my JScrollpane container!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`setPreferredScrollableViewportSize()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setPreferredScrollableViewportSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29) and a suitable layout.

Edit: You'll also need [`setFillsViewportHeight()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setFillsViewportHeight%28boolean%29), as discussed in [*Adding a Table to a Container*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#show).

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the XML file format.

If it is coded, you may need to code something like this:

```
JScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane();
JPanel1.add(JscrollPane1);
JScrollPane1.setBounds(5,29,636,122);

JTable1 = new JTable();    
JPanel1.add(JTable1);
JScrollPane1.setBounds(5,434,553,3097);
JScrollPane1.setViewportView(JTable1);
```